# Espresso : AmbiguousViewMatcherException : How to select 1st of 2nd record in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-espresso

Facing `AmbiguousViewMatcherException` while finding `ib_edit`

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.ib_edit),hasSibling(withText(activityUnderTest)),isDisplayed())).perform(click()) ;
```

`ib_edit` is a `ImageButton` located inside a `Horizontal` `LinearLayout`, Horizontal layout is inflated as a row under a `Vertical` `LinearLayout`. There are many records with same name and I am ok to select any one or specifically first or second.

```
llv_record_activities_3  (Linear Layout - Vertical ) 
llh_root_record_activity_3_item (Linear Layout - Horizontal - inflated under llv_record_activities_3  )
```

Could have managed if it was an `adapter view`, but unfortunately its not.
Please suggest if there is any way to manage it in `LinearLayout`.

**Exception** - `android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException`